# Unable to show a value from widget as TextView in an Activity

Tags: java, android, textview, widget

There is a project on github  https://github.com/codeka/advbatterygraph which shows different properties about battery such as instant current (mA/h) etc. in a widget. I downloaded the project, compiled it, ran it on my Nexus 5 and it worked fine.

What I am trying to do is to just get this **Instant Current (mA)** Value from this widget and show it in an Activity using TextView.

I studied the code to figure things out and I found that:
 1. The value is being stored in a String(curr) in [BatteryGraphWidgetProvider](https://github.com/codeka/advbatterygraph/blob/master/app/src/main/java/au/com/codeka/advbatterygraph/BatteryGraphWidgetProvider.java) class.
 2. BatteryStatus class has a method getBatteryCurrentInstant();

I tried something like this in my Activity but wasn't lucky enough:

```
BatteryStatus b = new BatteryStatus();
b.getBatteryCurrentInstant; 

/*Made a TextView Variable, and by using "findViewById" method I got the 
reference to that variable. Afterwards, I set it like this:*/

mMy_Variable.setText( (int) b.getBatteryCurrentInstant() );
```

**Outcome:** 
"Unfortunately, App stopped working".

Pardon me if this is too much of newbie question but I'm just getting started with android development and I'm quite sure everyone went through this phase. Any help/idea/suggestion as to how I could complete this task would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post the logcat along with additional java code

Comment: Here is the link to logcat text:
http://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1k9o and sorry what "additional java code" you are talking about? @KavachChandra

Answer (score 2):

android TextView has multiple implementations for `setText`. the one that accepts an integer value, tries to retrieve a string from your resources.
[read more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)). you should pass your value as `String`. you can use `Integer.toString(int)`.

Comment: I tried it and now the app is working but showing 0 instead of the value (mA) it should be.

Comment: It seems that `getBatteryCurrentInstant` returns zero. make sure that the widget is using this exact value.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I went through the whole code and saw that https://github.com/codeka/advbatterygraph/blob/master/app/src/main/java/au/com/codeka/advbatterygraph/BatteryGraphWidgetProvider.java (Please have a look If you don't mind) has a String variable "curr" which stores  the Current Instant value by using this statement:       
 
String curr = String.format(Locale.US,"%.2f mA (inst)", batteryHistory.get(0).getBatteryCurrentInstant());

Answer (score 0):

So, I checked the above library you've mentioned and the function you're using, `getBatteryCurrentInstant` returns the information in `float`. So, you'll need to modify your code as follows:

```
mMy_Variable.setText( Float.toString(b.getBatteryCurrentInstant()) );
```

OR

```
mMy_Variable.setText( String.valueOf(b.getBatteryCurrentInstant()) );
```

Comment: The value being returned from the function in the library must be 0.0 only. Try to get other values and check if they're returning expected values or not

Comment: It works fine in widget though but it doesn't in Activity.
okay, I'll try to do that.